# Better name for “vec transposition permutation matrix”?

Tags: matrices, permutations, matrix-theory

Let the operator vec($A$) unroll all the elements of $A$ into a single column vector in column-major order. Then, the elements of vec($A^T$) are a permutation of the elements of vec($A$). If I want to write this permutation as a matrix-vector product, I get

vec($A^T)$ = $P$ vec($A$).

I'm looking for a common name and/or symbol for the "vec transposition permutation matrix" $P$?

Comment: [Commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix)

Comment: In addition to the name "commutation matrix", this sometimes goes by the name "[swap gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Swap_gate)", and it appears lots in quantum computing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This matrix is known as the *commutation matrix*. For more details, please see Chapter 3, Section 7 of: [Matrix differential calculus](http://www.janmagnus.nl/misc/mdc2007-3rdedition) by Magnus and Neudecker.